# CodeIgniter mod-rewrite

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite

I can't realise mod rewrite in CI.
I tried this.

.htaccess

RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|js|uploads|css|sounds|images|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

routes.php:

`$route['category/:any'] = 'site/index';`

My Site:
[codergames.ru](http://codergames.ru/site/index?category=PHP)

Thank you.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: what I do wrong? 
It's not working now. 
It just showing /index content now nor /index?category=PHP

Comment: remove the `index` in `site/index`. put **site** *only*, CI will route it default to index so no need to put it.